# How to order django query set filtered using '__icontains' such that the exactly matched result comes first

Tags: django, database, python-2.7, django-models

I am writing a simple app in django that searches for records in database. 
Users inputs a name in the search field and that query is used to filter records using a particular field like -

```
Result = Users.objects.filter(name__icontains=query_from_searchbox)
```

E.g. -
Database consists of names- Shiv, Shivam, Shivendra, Kashiva, Varun... etc.

A search query 'shiv' returns records in following order-

> Kahiva, Shivam, Shiv and Shivendra

Ordered by primary key.

My question is how can i achieve the order -

> Shiv, Shivam, Shivendra and Kashiva.

I mean the most relevant first then lesser relevant result.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that with standard Django as that type of thing is outside the scope & specific to a search app.

When you're interacting with the ORM consider what you're actually doing with the database - it's all just SQL queries.

If you wanted to rearrange the results you'd have to manipulate the queryset, check exact matches, then use regular expressions to check for partial matches.

Search isn't really the kind of thing that is best suited to the ORM however, so you may which to consider looking at specific search applications. They will usually maintain an index, which avoids database hits and may also offer a percentage match ordering like you're looking for.

A good place to start may be with [Haystack](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/searchqueryset_api.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I found a way. I simply use two query set. In first query i filter out the names that start with the word ordered by name thus automatically putting the exact match first and then lesser matched. In second query I first exclude the names that start with the word and with the remaining names i filter out names which contain the word. I then simply join the two queries.

Comment: @ShivendraSinghVishen Right ok, well I'd still recommend looking at dedicated search apps, or at the very least some good caching on the model you're searching because that'll be quite database intensive.